# How do I get the Cobalt RC9 version?

Tags: git, cobalt

I want to get Cobalt RC9 from putty tool
How do I get it?
I apologize for the basic questions, but I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: Did you run the command 'git clone https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt'? It need to run git clone first, then run 'git checkout RC_9'.

Comment: I resolved it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use git command to change to RC_9 branch

git checkout RC_9

Comment: Thank you for reply!
After using git checkout RC_9 command "pathspec 'RC_9' did not match any file (s) known to git." How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a fresh git clone and try again?